# C# sql insert count of one table to another

Tags: c#, sql

Hello as I am inserting the count of one table data to another table I don't know how to do it as I am new to SQL and c# .net.Below is my code attached. data is inserting when i write this query:

```
Insert into compareresult(title,repeat) select  title, COUNT(*) as repeat from glassdoor  GROUP BY title HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 union select  title, COUNT(*) as repeat from mitula GROUP BY title HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 union select   title, COUNT(*) as repeat  from trovoit GROUP BY title HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1 union   select title, COUNT(*) as repeat from indeed GROUP BY title HAVING   COUNT(*)  > 1 intersect select   title, COUNT(*)  as repeat from alldata_table GROUP BY title HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

but it doesnt work when i use in .net web forms. code will be preferred.

```
void getIntersectedData()
    {

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = @" select  title, COUNT(*) as repeat from glassdoor  
            GROUP BY title HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 union select  title, COUNT(*) as repeat from mitula GROUP BY title HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
            union select   title, COUNT(*) as repeat  from trovoit GROUP BY title HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1 union   
            select title, COUNT(*) as repeat from indeed GROUP BY title HAVING   COUNT(*)  > 1 intersect 
            select   title, COUNT(*)  as repeat from alldata_table GROUP BY title HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                insert(dr);   
            }
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
    private void insert(SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        con.Open();
        string insertquery = @"Insert into compareresult(title,count) values('" + dr[0].ToString() + "','" + dr[1].ToString() + "')";
        SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(insertquery, con);
        cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Did you intend for your first block of code (the SQL statement) to be a single line? It's very hard to read. Can you be more descriptive than _"but it doesn't work"_

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure exactly what isn't working means.

Comment: I want to add the title and count of one table to another table but it is not inserting first i select the data from sql having same title and also count there repetition then i want to insert that data into new table how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

My first guess even though I need more details:

If the count(*) for each table is the same, union will ignore the duplicates. In this case, I would use union all to make sure it is the same.  Second, you might want to store the counts with a reference to the table you are taking the counts from.  Maybe another column to indicate the table?

Comment: I want to add the title and count of one table to another table but it is not inserting first i select the data from sql having same title and also count there repetition then i want to insert that data into new table how can i do this

Comment: I'm going to need more details on what's not working.  Are the counts off? Is there an exception?  It's very vague right now on what you are actually seeing.